# linux kde full disk encryption how to bruteforce

Tags: linux, encryption, kde, brute-force

how do i bruteforce a linux kde full disk encryption. i get to please unlock disk sda5 crypt. I have an apprioximate idea of the password i used. It can only be a few words but because i alphanumeric and sometimes i add dashes or fullstops and also the possiblity of mistyoing by accident i have forgotten the password. I have no idea how to bruteforce. I am also noob at linux. Please help and i will love you forever.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what KDE has to do with full disk encryption, but I believe [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat) would be able to do what you need. It supports LUKS (and Veracrypt/Truecrypt).

But this is not for a beginner, at all.

You would need to get the key from the drive, and then run hashcat against that.

Or, alternatively, attach the drive and have hashcat generate combinations, and feed those into a script to try and unlock the drive.

You can specify the structure of the target password via hashcat command line options (eg. 8 characters, first 3 are alpha, then a dash, then the rest are numeric or whatever you believe it is).

You better have a really close idea of what that password is though, because if you don't you'll die of old age before guessing the correct one.

See: https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-6225.html

Comment: First of all many thanks on taking the time to reply - much appreciated. Kde is the linux version installed on the hd and on first install it has the option to full encrypt the hd. I will look into the options you have mentioned. Thank you once again.

Comment: No, KDE is a window manager, independant of whatever distribution of Linux you are running. And whatever encryption you are using is independent of that.

Comment: Not quite. KDE is a desktop environment. I believe its standard window manager is KWin, but there are others.